# Mongo faster than MongoClient

Tags: php, mongodb

[Mongo::__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.construct.php) is deprecated following php.net, and it's faster 3 times than MongoClient!!

Try it yourself, run the below code which insert 1M docuements, it will finish in ~20 sec the replace mongo with mongoClient which will finish in ~180 sec

```
<?php

function mongo_connect($db, $collection) {
    $mongo = new Mongo( 'mongodb://localhost' );
    return $mongo->$db->$collection;

}

$mongodb='notificator1';
$mongocollection='tok';
$collection= mongo_connect($mongodb, $mongocollection);

echo $time = microtime(true). "\n";

$i=0;
while ( $i < 1000000 ) {
    $row = Array('title' => "test #$i");
    $collection->save($row);
    ++$i;
}

echo microtime(true) - $time;

?>
```

replace mongo_connect:

```
function mongo_connect($db, $collection) {
    $m = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017');
    $db = $m->selectDB($db);
    return $collection = new MongoCollection($db, $collection);
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: The question is how to benefit from the new class (mongoClient) and maintain the same performance.

Comment: Obligatory mongodb performance link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2F-DItXtZs

Answer (score 2):

Mongo is faster but that IS NOT A GOOD THING.

But the answer to your actual question is in the code:

```
$mongo = new Mongo( 'mongodb://localhost' );
```

The default write concern of `Mongo` is `0` which means it won't bother to check if the write actually worked whereas `MongoClient` will.

Here is a good post that explains the differences between `Mongo` and `MongoClient` form one of the mantainers of PHP and the MongoDB Driver: http://derickrethans.nl/mongoclient.html .

> Now, you may be wondering why we are replacing Mongo with MongoClient across the board. The biggest reason is that the new class will have acknowledged writes on by default

Comment: there no param settings we can add to **Mongoclient** and have the same performance of **Mongo**??

Comment: @user1231317 Yes set its writeconcern to 0 http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.setwriteconcern.php

Comment: I tried writeconcern() but i'm getting undefined method (fatal error), why do you think?

Comment: @user1231317 can you edit the question with a code sample? It is `setWriteConcern(0)` as well not writeconern()

Comment: $m = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$db = $m->selectDB($db);
$db->setWriteConcern(0);
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, $collection);
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method MongoDB::setWriteConcern()

Comment: @user1231317 You need to set it on the `$m` variable

Comment: you can also set it in the connection query string if with the `w` flag: $m = new MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017?w=0');  More info: http://derickrethans.nl/mongoclient.html.